# Pretty-print using the new Ruby syntax for hashes

Tags: json, ruby, hash, pretty-print

There's a ton of questions about Ruby pretty-printing of recursive structures à la JSON (i.e, just scalars, arrays and hashes), and the answers refer to the json, pp, awesome_printer, etc.  However, I have not seen a way to pretty-print a hash in Ruby syntax, that in addition would please classical Ruby linters.  Something like

```
> pretty({a: [1, 2, {b: 3, c: 4}], d: {e: {'f g': 42}}})
=> "{a: [1, 2, {b: 3, c: 4}], d: {e: {'f g': 42}}}"
```

awesome_print comes close:

```
> ({a: [1, 2, {b: 3, c: 4}], d: {e: {'f g': 42}}}).
    ai(plain: true, multiline: false, ruby19_syntax: true)
=> "{ a: [ 1, 2, { b: 3, c: 4 } ], d: { e: { \"f g\": 42 } } }"
```

but I didn't find a means to get rid of the inner spaces for braces and brackets, and it chose to use double-quotes for a constant string, which is disliked by Rubocop.

I can write my pretty-printer myself, but I'm surprised there's no COTS^h^h^h^hgem that does that.  Did I miss something?

Comment: I don't think I understand. That's JSON, not Ruby. Does Rubocop critique JSON? Can you show an example of when this is a linter issue?

Comment: @Schwern: Nit picking: That's not JSON, JSON requires keys and strings to be double quoted so JSON would be `{"a": [1, 2, {"b": 3, "c": 4}], "d": {"e": {"f g": 42}}}`. And newer Rubies allow symbols to be quoted when using the JavaScript-style syntax (i.e. `{'f g': 42}` is valid Ruby). Sorry, this is my Ruby pet peeve.

Comment: not sure what you mean, "that would please classical Ruby linters"

Comment: For instance Rubocop prefers single quotes for literal strings that don't need escapes and interpolation, and prefer the new syntax for hash.  However, they appears to have no support in standard Ruby to pretty-print structures this way.  One has to write her own pretty-printer apparently.